# ffmpeg to extract a video one frame per second?

Tags: linux, ffmpeg

Currently I am using command line to extract pictures from video.

```
ffmpeg -i ../m.mp4 -f image2 m.mp4-%04d.bmp
```

This results too many frames.

I would like to extract pictures from a video, one frame per second of video. Preferably with multithreading.

Answer (score 11):

Use `-r 1` as an output option:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -r 1 %04d.bmp
```

Results in `0001.bmp`, `0002.bmp`, `0003.bmp`, etc.

The BMP encoder currently has no threading capabilities as shown by `ffmpeg -h encoder=bmp`.